# Grouping based on value by date range

Tags: oracle, group-by, date-range

Hi i have a data in daily basis below:

```
daytime        value
01.01.2017     20000
02.01.2017     20000
03.01.2017     20000
04.01.2017     35000
05.01.2017     35000
06.01.2017     40000
07.01.2017     40000
08.01.2017     50000
```

How can i have in date range format such as below?

```
FromDate     ToDate      Value
01.01.2017   03.01.2017  20000
04.01.2017   05.01.2017  35000
06.01.2017   07.01.2017  40000
08.01.2017   08.01.2017  50000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) handles this very easily:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') daytime, 20000 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('02/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') daytime, 20000 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('03/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') daytime, 20000 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('04/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') daytime, 35000 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') daytime, 35000 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('06/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') daytime, 40000 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('07/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') daytime, 40000 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('08/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') daytime, 50000 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('09/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') daytime, 20000 VALUE FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking your table with data in it. See SQL below:
SELECT MIN(daytime) fromdate,
       MAX(daytime) todate,
       VALUE
FROM   (SELECT daytime,
               VALUE,
               row_number() OVER (ORDER BY daytime) - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY VALUE ORDER BY daytime) grp
        FROM   your_table)
GROUP BY grp,
         VALUE
ORDER BY MIN(daytime);

FROMDATE   TODATE          VALUE
---------- ---------- ----------
01/01/2017 03/01/2017      20000
04/01/2017 05/01/2017      35000
06/01/2017 07/01/2017      40000
08/01/2017 08/01/2017      50000
09/01/2017 09/01/2017      20000
```

What this does is compare the row number for all the rows ordered by date, and then the row number for all the rows for each value ordered by date. If the value rows are consecutive in the main set of data, then the difference between the two sets of data remains the same, so you can then group by that. If there is a gap, then the difference increases.

In your example above, the first three rows for value = 20000 happen to be the first three rows of the whole set, so the difference will be 0. However the fourth value = 20000 row is the 9th row in the whole set, so the difference is now 5. You can easily see that the value of 20000 falls into two groups, and as such, you can find the min/max daytime for each group separately by including that difference calculation in the group by clause.

N.B. This does assume that the dates in your data are consecutive or that if there are missing dates that you assume the value stays the same for the missing dates. If you do have missing days and you want the values across a gap to show in different groups, you'd need to outer join to a subquery that contains the missing dates. In that case, I think GurV's answer (with the additional clause in the case statement that I mentioned in the comments) would be the best one to use, as that would avoid the need to outer join to a list of consecutive dates.

Comment: Not sure how you mean the N.B. - perhaps you mean if there are ten rows at the top, all with the value 20000 but the dates are four consecutive days, then a gap, and then six more consecutive days, and that should produce two rows instead of one... If that is what you mean, then a minor modification of **Tabibitosan** can deal with that directly. To create `grp`, use `daytime` itself instead of the first `row_number()`; this way the `grp` values will end up being dates instead of numbers, but the whole thing works exactly the same way.

Comment: Good point, ta; I'd never thought of doing that before! Will have a play around with that on Monday *{:-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to group the value only if they are same for consecutive dates.

You can use window functions to generate groups based on value and increasing date order and then find the required aggregates.

```
with your_table(daytime      ,value) as (
    select to_date('13.02.2017','dd.mm.yyyy'),25000 from dual union all
    select to_date('14.02.2017','dd.mm.yyyy'),20000 from dual union all
    select to_date('15.01.2017','dd.mm.yyyy'),90000 from dual union all
    select to_date('16.01.2017','dd.mm.yyyy'),90000 from dual union all
    select to_date('17.01.2017','dd.mm.yyyy'),95800 from dual union all
    select to_date('18.01.2017','dd.mm.yyyy'),95800 from dual union all
    select to_date('19.01.2017','dd.mm.yyyy'),95800 from dual union all
    select to_date('20.01.2017','dd.mm.yyyy'),95800 from dual union all
    select to_date('21.01.2017','dd.mm.yyyy'),95800 from dual union all
    select to_date('22.01.2017','dd.mm.yyyy'),95800 from dual union all
    select to_date('23.01.2017','dd.mm.yyyy'),95800 from dual union all
    select to_date('24.01.2017','dd.mm.yyyy'),90000 from dual union all
    select to_date('25.01.2017','dd.mm.yyyy'),90000 from dual union all
    select to_date('26.01.2017','dd.mm.yyyy'),90000 from dual 
)
select
    min(daytime) fromdate,
    max(daytime) todate,
    value
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(x) over (order by daytime) grp
    from (
        select 
            t.*,
            case when value = lag(value) over (order by daytime) 
            then 0 else 1 end x
        from your_table t
    ) t
) t group by grp, value
order by fromdate;
```

Produces:

```
FROMDATE    TODATE      VALUE
15-JAN-17   16-JAN-17   90000
17-JAN-17   23-JAN-17   95800
24-JAN-17   26-JAN-17   90000
13-FEB-17   13-FEB-17   25000
14-FEB-17   14-FEB-17   20000
```

Comment: Hi i see duplicated value with your solution, i will show example later on, thanks!

Comment: @akirax what do you mean you see duplicated values with GurV's solution? It looks like it works for me, when I try it with some test data. It certainly gives the output you put in your answer for the input data you supplied.

Comment: @GurV regarding the phantom groups you mentioned at one point on my answer, if you were referring to the groups created across gaps in the dates then your answer as it stands also suffers from the same issue, but can be easily corrected by adding `AND daytime = LAG(daytime) OVER (ORDER BY daytime) + 1` into your case statement. If that was a case the OP was concerned about, I would suggest your answer is better than mine, because it doesn't need to be outer joined to a list of consecutive dates.